# How to add checkbox to custom grid via Renderer\AbstractRenderer or Renderer\Checkbox?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2

I have to add a column checkbox based on a column from DB.
[image]

Checkbox column is appearing in the grid, but I can't change(grid doesn't change after save) the value of the checkbox and it always stays unchecked... How to achieve it?

Comment: Can you try to change to 'renderer' => \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\Checkbox::class?

Comment: You also need to add a value for type when using Checkbox